# Python: Can optparse have the ACTION attribute to act both like STORE and STORE_TRUE?

Tags: python, action, store, argparse, optparse

I am using `optparse` to get command line input.

Lets say that I am running a script `demo.py` and it creates some output. But unless I specify the command line input, the output is not written to a file.

I am trying to do the following:

`python demo.py` in command line should run the script, but not write the output anywhere.

`python demo.py -o` in command line should write the output to my default file name `output.txt`.

`python demo.py -o demooutput.txt` in command line should write the output to file `demooutput.txt`.

PS: I would not prefer to switch to `argparse` from `optparse`.

Comment: *I would not prefer to switch to `argparse` from `optparse`*. A pity, because that'd would make your use-case trivial to implement.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am unable to use argparse as I am forced to run using older version of python.

Comment: How old a version? `argparse` works well with (or at least, there is available a version compatible with) Python 2.4 once it is installed.

Comment: @chepner: I am using python 2.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [optparse-callbacks](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse-option-callbacks) to achieve this.

Here is how it wiill work for your use case.

```
parser.add_option("-o", action="callback", dest="output", callback=my_callback)

def my_callback(option, opt, value, parser):
     if len(parser.rargs) > 0:
         next_arg = parser.rargs[0]
         if not next_arg.startswith("-"):
             # Next argument is not another option
             del parser.rargs[0]
             setattr(parser.values, option.dest, next_arg)
             return
     # If not processed, set the default value
     setattr(parser.values, option.dest, "output.txt")
```

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit according to my needs. Works great!
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is unfortunately - the only way I can think of is hacking around the problem by adding your own logic statements. The following code should do the trick.

```
import re, sys
import optparse from OptionParser    
usage = "usage: %prog [options] arg"
parser = OptionParser(usage)
if '-f' in argv:
    a = argv.index('-f')
    if (a != len(argv)-1) and re.search('[.]txt', argv[a+1]):
        parser.add_option("-f", "--foo", dest="foo")
    else:
        parser.add_option("-f", dest="foo", action="store_true")
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the direct question, 'how to define an Action...', but it handles the inputs in a simple way.

Set `'-o'` to be `'store_true'`.  If True check the `'args'` variable for a file name.

```
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
if options.o:
    if args:
        dest = args[0]
    else:
        dest = 'output.txt'
else:
    dest = ''
```

(In `argparse` the equivalent would be to define a positional argument with `nargs='?'`.)

If these are the only arguments, you could also get by with checking for the filename without requiring the `` `-o' ``.

Another possibility - 'store_const', with the positional 'filename' having priority:

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-o',dest='dest',action='store_const', const='output.txt', default='')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
if args:
    options.dest = args[0]
print options
```

Comment: I dont think this will work if I have more than one optional input.
Say "python demo.py [-o outputfilename] [-s startvalue]. Note that the 'startvalue' input too is optional.

Comment: In that case `argparse` with `nargs='?'` has a big advantage.  You can use `argparse` with an older Python by just placing a copy of `argparse.py` in your own code directory.

Comment: Yea it will work with nargs='?'. Thanks. In my opinion, it isnt a good practice to copy import files to working directory. If I didn't have optparse, I might have gone that way.
Thanks a lot for your help!